# Связь LoginServer и GameServer

Tags: c++, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер, tcp

Например, клиент подключается к LoginServer, после чего проходит аутентификацию.Как связать клиента с GameServer? Может как-то можно передать дескриптор GameServer? Или как это делается? 
П.С. Клиентом является онлайн игра с закрытым исходным кодом.

Comment: lineage что ли?

Comment: Нет.Tales of Pirates.

Comment: Вот нашел: "Либо можно сделать Gateway - это отдельный процесс который будет принимать всё на один сокет, он же будет держать все соеднинения. Далее будет решать куда переправлять сообщения, на логин сервер или на игровой логики сервер. Таким образом разрывать не нужно будет. Плюс, ддос атаки будут валить скорее Gateway. Также там можно реализовать бан листы и т.п." А как сделать, чтобы LoginServer отработал, разорвал соединение, GameServer принял работу?